# Check if iOS Device Token is valid

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am working on iOS app Push Notifications with PHP. Whenever the app is opened ,it sends a device token to the remote server . Now while sending the notification to all the device tokens , Looping through all the device tokens to send notification . I want to delete the invalid tokens on the check by checking response someone . I tried many workarounds like reading the response with fread . But doesn't seems to work .

P.S: Is there any other Apple API to check if device token is valid ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW10)
from Apple.

go to **HTTP/2 Response from APNs** header and check this table:

[image]